# Placing K gas stations among n cities to minimize distance

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming, big-o-notation

> There are $n$ cities on a highway with coordinates $x_1$
> , . . . , $x_n$ and we aim to build $K < n$ gas stations
> to cover these cities. Each gas station has to be built in one of the cities, and we hope to minimize the
> average distance from each city to the closest gas station. Please give an algorithm to compute the optimal
> way to place these $K$ gas stations. The algorithm should run in $O(n^2K)$ time.

I brute forced the answer by finding every single possible placement of gas stations and returning the minimum combo. Then I spent way too long fiddling with different ideas in Python to try and reduce the big-$O$ notation to no avail. Eventually I found a thread on the subject, but the formula isn't working for me.

[How to minimize the average distance between pumps and cities?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/101269/how-to-minimize-the-average-distance-between-pumps-and-cities)

I tried replicating the formula given in this thread in Python and it just doesn't work. It comes *close* but no dice. Here's my code (assume "cities" is the list of cities):

```python
def f(n, k):
    if k == 1: # if k is 1, return total distance from the cities to the median 
        pump = n // 2
        return sum([abs(loc - cities[pump]) for loc in cities[:n]])

    min_list = []
    for i in range(n-1):
        sum_list = []
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            pumpk = ((j + 1) + (n-1)) // 2 
            sum_list.append(abs(cities[j] - cities[pumpk]) + f(i, k-1))
        min_list.append(sum(sum_list))
    return min(min_list)
```

I'm at such a loss! How can I solve the problem with the required time-complexity?

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem statement?  We require you to credit the original source of all quoted material or material originally written by others: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Can I ask you to [edit] your question to comply with that policy?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that the recurrence relation is not implemented correctly in the code given in the question.

---

Here is a correct implementation.

```python
# `cities` is a list of increasing integers that gives the
# locations of all cities such as follows
cities = [1, 5, 20, 22, 40, 100, 110]
K = 2


def min_sum_distances(start, end):
  """ Cities between `start` inclusive and `end` exclusive. One pump is installed."""
  pump_loc = start + end >> 1
  return sum(abs(city - cities[pump_loc]) for city in cities[start:end])


def min_sum(total_pumps):
  n = len(cities)

  # `dp[c][p]` is the minimum sum of distances from the first `c` cities
  # to the nearest pump when `p` pumps are installed.
  # 1 <= c <= n and 1 <= p <= K
  dp = [[float("infinity")] * (K + 1) for number_of_pumps in range(n + 1)]
  for c in range(1, n + 1):
    dp[c][1] = min_sum_distances(0, c)
    for p in range(2, min(c + 1, total_pumps + 1)):
      for cities_covered_before in range(p - 1, c):
        dp[c][p] = min(dp[c][p], dp[cities_covered_before][p - 1]
            + min_sum_distances(cities_covered_before, n))
return dp[n][total_pumps]


print(min_sum(K) / len(cities))
# 9.42857142857
```

The implementation runs in $O(n^3K)$ time.

---

In order to spend up the performance, we can reimplement `min_sum_distance` so that it runs in $O(1)$ instead of $O(n)$. We can use precomputed prefix sums of `cities`.

```python
from itertools import accumulate
pre_sums = list(accumulate(cities, initial=0))

def min_sum_distances(start, end):
  pump_loc = start + end >> 1
  return pre_sums[start] + pre_sums[end] - 2 * pre_sums[pump_loc] \
      - (cities[pump_loc] if (end - start) & 1 else 0)
```

With the improvement, the implementation runs in $O(n^2K)$ time.

Comment: Could you explain what this algorithm does and why?